# Navigation View seems to alter color of background

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components, material-components-android, android-navigationview

I would like to have my Navigation View's background be #121212, however it turns to be a much lighter grey. However a item in the view has the proper color displayed when the same color is applied as it's background.

```
android:background="@color/navview"
app:itemBackground="@color/navview"
```

The test item's background is set to the same color as the Navigation View background, however there is a staggering difference in colors as shown below.

[image]

Is there a filter on the navigation view background? I have tried disabling it by setting the background tint mode to null,

```
        nvView.backgroundTintMode = null
```

however it seems to have no effect. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/navview"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/navview"
        app:itemBackground="@color/navview"

        app:menu="@menu/toolbar_menu">


    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My Navigation View's Background is not the right color, the item's background is the right color. The color i am trying to achieve is #121212.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `NavigationView` use the **`itemShapeFillColor`** attribute to fill the item and `android:background` for the background of the menu view.

In the layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:background="#121212"
    app:itemShapeFillColor="@color/..."
    ../>
```

[image]

(I just use an alpha on selected item just to highlight it)

You can also use a style:

```
<style name="..." parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView" >
   <item name="itemShapeFillColor">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

Just a note about the `itemBackground`.

In the default style is set to `@null` to use a shaped background programmatically generated by `NavigationView` when **`itemShapeAppearance`** and/or `itemShapeAppearanceOverlay` is set.
This background is styled using the **`itemShape*`** attributes (as `itemShapeFillColor`, `itemShapeInsetStart`...).
Setting `itemBackground` will overwrite the programmatic background and cause values set in the `itemShape*` attributes to be ignored.

Comment: I do understand as to why the items in the navview are colored like that, however my problem is that I want the navbackground to be the same color as the items. Instead it appears as a lighter gray variant of #121212

Comment: post your layout and your color/selector

Comment: @A.D Just tried the code in the answer with 1.1.0-beta02 and 1.2.0-alpha02 and it works with the right color. Updated the answer.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti If I use `itemShapeFillColor` then all items' (not only selected one) background color is set to that color. How can I make it for only selected item?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of navigation view using following snippet of code

```
navView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.yourColor)) // yourColor is 
                                                                           // #121212
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the accepted answer does not solve what I needed, and what I understand that the question requests: keeping the NavigationView from modifying the background color provided.

In case someone else needs this, I achieved it by adding the following attributes to the Navigation view:

```
android:backgroundTintMode="add"
android:backgroundTint="#000"
```

This disables the tint that is applied to the background, as it adds 0 to the current color.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix it is by set your DrawerLayout elevation to 0dp

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp" <!-- here -->
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar_layout"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

 <!-- Another view -->

 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
  ...
  ...
  android:background="@color/nav_color" />

 </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then you get the right color for your NavigationView